# convert svg and xml into a video

Tags: javascript, html, video, svg

I have recorded some drawing into an svg file. Now I can play it back in a browser using HTML5 and javascript, but what i'd like to do is convert it to a video format.

I can extract the data for each frame, but I don't know how to draw them (except in JS), and furthermore I don't know how to convert those frames to a movie. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/48532/convert-animated-svg-to-movie